# NEHotspotHelper - possible to test without entitlement?

Tags: ios, entitlements

is it possible to test prototype app (development deployment) using NEHotspotHelper - connecting from app to WiFi without the actual need to request com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper entitlement and wait for weeks to (maybe) get it? Thanks

Comment: Any luck with it, @Tom?

Comment: No, not really, not in any proper/nice way. We've decided to use .mobileconfig (hosted within the app) to configure everything - so user just has to click accept and then it would either autoconnect or he can just connect manually but without any passwords and stuff. I believe that's the best we can do in this restricted environment.

Answer (score 2):

You need a jailbreak device.

You can write any entitlements you like to the `.entitlements` file, then build and run the app on a jailbreak device.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm unfortunately on 9.2.1 so no way (as of yet) to jailbreak :(

Comment: @Tom Hey Tom, tell me if you find something, I'm looking for using NEHotspotHelper too...

Comment: Well, I sent request to Apple and they've replied really quickly with refusal unfortunately (though I still thinks are situation was a valid use case).